# Get first two digits of a long long number

Tags: c, long-long

Hello I have a `long long` number which varies from 13,15, and 16 digits in length. I want to get the first two digits(from the left) of these numbers.
For example:

```
Enter Number = 1234567890123;
First 2 digits = 12
Enter Number = 453456789012345;
First 2 digits = 45
Enter Number = 3534567890123456;
First 2 digits = 35
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What part of the problem do you not understand as far as a C implementation? Are you familiar with C arithmetic operators? If not, you should check the C documentation.

Comment: As a quick and very dirty hack you can convert the number to a string, use a substring with length 2 and then parse that string back to a number.

Comment: Especially if the number is available at compile-time, then it is no longer a dirty hack but the correct solution. This looks like a run-time variable and then the accepted answer is fine, but I posted a compile-time version just for reference.

Comment: Convert the number to a string, reverse the string, convert it back to an integer, take it `% 100`, convert it to a string again, reverse it again.  Convert to an integer once more at the end, if necessary. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeatedly divide by 10 until 0 is reached, remembering the antepenultimate value of the number, which you will eventually return as the result.

In other words,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long long n = 3534567890123456; 
    long long n1 = n, n2 = n; // n2 will hold the first two digits. 
    while (n){
        n2 = n1;
        n1 = n;
        n /= 10;
    }   
    printf("%lld", n2); 
}
```

I initialise `n1` and `n2` to `n` so the correct result is returned if the magnitude of `n` is less than 100.

Note that this algorithm carelessly considers an unnecessary step (you don't need to run `n` right down to `0`) but doing so saves having to worry about negative `n` cases, and `n1` also yields the first digit, which could be useful.

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm.

Comment: @DynamicQ: It's a bit naughty giving a solution like this, so please do make sure you understand what's going on here.

Comment: What would I do If I needed just the first digit?

Comment: @DynamicQ `n1` ends up being the first digit.

Comment: @DynamicQ: If you know that these numbers will usually have more than 13 digits, you can spare a couple of CPU clocks by doing `if (n > 1e11L) n /= 1e11L;` right before the `while` loop. Or, a more general way to get rid of the digits (without using `log`) would be to binary search the "best" number of decimals. This is, of course, not relevant for a simple home assignment.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the number is available at compile-time, you can extract it at compile-time by converting it to a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER 1234567890123

#define STR(n) #n
#define FIRST(n)  STR(n)[0]
#define SECOND(n) STR(n)[1]

int main(void)
{
  printf("%c %c", FIRST(NUMBER), SECOND(NUMBER));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to account for negative numbers, a slightly simpler version of @Bathsheba's algorithm would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long n = 3534567890123456;

    // divide until we get to 10..99
    while (n >= 100)
        n /= 10;

    printf("%lld", n);
    return 0;
}
```

If you also know the number is larger than 13 digits, you can divide it by <strike>`1e11`</strike> (`1e11` is a floating point literal, see comments below) `100000000000` at the beginning, to reduce the number of iterations inside the loop. You can also invert negative numbers, if these are a possible input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long n = 3534567890123456;

    // handle negative numbers
    if (n < 0)
        n = -n; 

    // get rid of 11 digits
    if (n >= 100000000000)
        n /= 100000000000;

    // handle the remaining digits 
    while (n >= 100)
        n /= 10;

    printf("%lld", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to divide by integer `100000000000`, to reduce likelihood of floating-point errors (and also to improve performance).

Comment: Big, big oops here. `1e11` is a `double` constant and that causes type conversion of the other argument! Else the approach is a good one.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Thanks for the tip, dividing by double is a really bad idea, there would surely be cases where it would give a wrong result, I had the terribly wrong idea that `1e11` would be a seen as a `long long` literal by the compiler in this case.

Comment: This does have trouble with the pesky corner case: `long long n = LLONG_MIN;`  That value though is unlikely to be "13,15, and 16" digits in length.